# Redis high availability and load balancing

Tags: load-balancing, cluster, failover, redis

I'm using Redis for some time and now we want to move to a redundant cluster which would be fault tolerant, highly available and load balanced.

I principally use Redis for some PHP web application which stores some process status information (I'm using PHPRedis for this) and I would like to use it also for PHP session store in a load balanced cluster.

I already have a Load Balancing that I use for Nginx and MySQL (based on pfSense).

I saw that Redis Cluster exists for Redis 3, but I also read some comments about the fact that it is not ready for production, others that tells that Redis cannot do a complete master/master cluster configuration.

What is your advise?

- Try Redis Cluster
- Move to another key=value engine (CouchDB? Memcached? Others?)
- Don't mind about load balancing and use only one node of the cluster per time, and having a manual failover, as I don't use persistence
- Other ideas?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redis Sentinel will allow you to run multiple instances of redis and handles failover for you.  http://redis.io/topics/sentinel

Comment: // , Mat, did it work?

Comment: The question specifically mentions load balancing, which Sentinel doesn't do. You should at least address that in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious solution to loadbalance redis is to use [sentinel](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel).

As far as I can see predis does not support sentinel as of now. See:

https://github.com/nrk/predis/issues/131

A possible solution can be [Redis sentinel + HAProxy failover](https://serverfault.com/questions/548035/redis-sentinel-haproxy-failover?rq=1) if you want to keep using predis.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens maybe I am not following you correctly but as far as I see the question is how to loadbalance redis. I am pointing out that an obvious solution like sentinel will not work when using predis. Possibly that was not clear from my answer.

Comment: ok, that helps a bit to better understand your answer. I think you should edit it to somehow integrate that in it also (and then delete your comment).